# Apply ':focus' style to input-group

Tags: html, css

I have a from with normal `Bootstrap` `inputs` and also '.input-group`.

When i click in the normal `input` the focus looks fine as it highlights the whole field

[image]

But for an `input` with a `.input-group' it doesn't look nice (to me anyway)

[image]

I want the:

- % field to have `border-top`, `border-bottom`, `border-right`
- `input` NOT to have `border-right`

So far i have the following which remove `css`

```
if ($('input').is(':focus')) {
    $('.form-control:focus').css('border-right', '0');
    $('.input-group-append').addClass('inputGroupEndFocus');
```

So far i have the below

[image]

To get this, this is the `css`

```
.inputGroupEndFocus {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #80bdff;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, .25);
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-left: 0;
}
```

This is the `HTML`

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="creditLimitField" class="col-2 col-form-label">Percentage markup</label>
    <div class="col-2" style="padding: 0">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="markupPercentField" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter a markup percentage" value="20">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text font-weight-bold">%</span>
            </div>
            <div id="markupPercentFieldError" class="invalid-feedback">
                Percentage cannot be <span id="percentError"></span>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have 2 remaining issues i can't reslove:

1. There is still a right line on the input (suspect is something to do
   with the `box-shadow`)
2. I only want it to apply to the `input` with
   the `focus` but at the moment it adds it to all my `input-groups` as
   i have no ID's, names etc set on them

Comment: Its probably easier to just use `.input-group:focus-within { outline: 2px solid blue; } .input-group:focus-within *:focus { outline: none; border: none; }` (or whatever styling you want). Not supported everywhere but should do the trick on modern browsers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `:focus-within` pseudo selector, it might make things a lot easier:

```css
.input-group:focus-within {
  outline: 4px solid red;
}
.input-group:focus-within *:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

/* Just some general nice styling */
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.input-group input {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.input-group input,
.input-group span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  height: 1.5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.input-group input + *,
.input-group span + * {
  border-left: none;
}
.input-group span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input id="markupPercentField" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter a markup percentage" value="20" />
  <span class="input-group-text font-weight-bold">%</span>
</div>
```

Here's the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: Thanks.  Needed to add `$('.form-control:focus').css('box-shadow', 'none').css('border-color', 'transparent');` though

Comment: @murday1983 II feel you are better of putting that in your stylesheet than handling it with javascript.

Comment: i have done. I added it to the `.input-group:focus-within *:focus`

Answer (score 5):

**CSS Only Solution for Bootstrap 5:**

I take the whole css code from the bootstrap class `.form-control:focus` and additionally `border-radius: .25rem;` from `.form-control` and add them to my custom css code to the class `.input-group:focus-within`.
I also removed the default shadow from `.form-control:focus` by using `box-shadow: none !important;` on `.input-group .form-control:focus`. This avoids the double shadow.

```css
.input-group:focus-within {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #86b7fe;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.25rem rgb(13 110 253 / 25%);
    z-index: 3;
    border-radius: .25rem;
}
.input-group .form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <p>Examples</p>
  
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me BS5

```
.input-group:focus-within .input-group-text{
  border-top: 3px solid $typo-dark-purple;
  border-bottom: 3px solid $typo-dark-purple;
  border-left: 3px solid $typo-dark-purple;
}
```